# Is $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] dangerous, if I use a array of predefined URL's for validation?

Tags: php, security, xss

I am doing a login page for my application. When a user wants to go to "myaccount.php" but he's not logged in, he's redirected to login.php.

When login is successful, I want him to be redirected to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, which will be various pages of my application.

I read on forum that `['HTTP_REFERER']` can be dangerous.

But what if I create an array like ('myaccount.php','mycart.php', etc...) and compare this array to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, will this protect me against potential malicious use of this feature?

Comment: "I read on forum that ['HTTP_REFERER'] can be dangerous." What forum? What did you read?

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is *not reliable*. Is it dangerous? That depends on how the *not reliable client-supplied* information is used. Honestly, I have seen very little use for it for the "main" part of an application, so I am tempted to question it's use...

Comment: Referer is stripped if you move between http and https, and some firewalls/proxies will strip it for privacy reasons. Other frameworks typically add a returnUrl parameter to the link to the login page, and the use a whitelistbased validation before redirecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is not dangerous - it's just attacker controlled. It won't hurt you unless you trust it for granting extra permissions to someone (e.g. don't assume that someone who just came from successful-login.php has successfully logged in!)

Redirecting a user doesn't grant any special permissions to the user, so redirecting an attacker to an attacker-controlled string does not compromise your server's security in any way.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, it is not particularly dangerous to redirect to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` because if the end user was doing something malicious, he would just end up redirected at the referrer maliciously injected.  As long as you check permissions at the beginning of each script, it would not be possible for the user to reach an area of your site that he should not have access to (like an admin console). If, however, you failed to check permissions on each script and a user crafted a false referrer header, it could be used to direct into an area of your site that isn't supposed to be accessible.

In general though, `HTTP_REFERRER` isn't a particular source of danger. It just cannot be relied on to be set and to hold correct information.

Comment: +1 Well stated.  To the asker, if you are really concerned about malicious URLs, it sounds like you could simply check that the referring URL you will redirect to belongs to your domain.  If it does not, then forward them to some default location.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your responses.

WHen you talk about checking permissions, is it on a PHP level, such as check if isset($_SESSION...) ?

Comment: @eric01 Yes, that was what I was referring to - check that the currently logged in user (via PHP session or the db, whatever), is allowed to see the page he lands on.

Answer (score 2):

> I read on forum that `['HTTP_REFERER']` can be dangerous.

I believe the two most common flaws associated with this are [header injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection) and [open redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect)

If you only allow redirection based on an internal set of whitelisted URLs, like you've suggested, however, then I don't see a problem.